# Relative Cell Reference within Match Function Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Why can't I use the relative cell reference within the match function?  This works as intended if I instead use an absolute cell reference, however I need  excel to move to the next row with each cell evaluated in the range.  For example first iteration compares B29, next iteration compares B30,  next iteration evaluates B31, and so on.  Please help!

```
Sub Test()

    For Each cell In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F29:F50")
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(RC[-3], Range("Interior_Lining_Scuffs_Floors"), 0)) Then
            cell.Value = "Interior Lining/Scuffs/Floors"
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this one:

```
For Each cell In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F29:F50")
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(cell.Offset(,-3), Range("Interior_Lining_Scuffs_Floors"), 0)) Then
        cell.Value = "Interior Lining/Scuffs/Floors"
    End If
Next
```

Comment: WORKED PERFECTLY! I knew there had had to be an easy fix for this.  THANKS A LOT TIM!!!